# How to implement row ordering in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement a UI feature for a listings page where the user can change the order of the records they have created.

I'd assume one way to do it would be to store a position field with some kind of editable auto-increment rule; The position values of rows could then be swapped as the user raises or the lowers the position. However I'm not quite sure how that would be done, I'm still a Rails newbie.

I should also mention that I am trying to a avoid solutions that tie me to a particular database.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[acts_as_list](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) is the standard solution here. You will have a `position` column in your model that will hold the ordering.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out plugins and correct usage, but it works really well! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a commment/addition to the accepted answer above.

acts_as_list is not designed for anything beyond a prototype, and out of the box it does not handle concurrency or data integrity at all. At the very least, you must set your isolation level to serializable! Here's a [short screen cast](http://rhnh.net/2010/06/30/acts-as-list-will-break-in-production) with more information, and some workarounds.